# How to use mrjob.cat to auto-decompress inputs?

Tags: python, mapreduce, compression, mapper, mrjob

I want to use MrJob to analyze a dataset without decompressing it on disk beforehand (it is 18Gb compressed but >3Tb uncompressed). How can I use use [mrjob.cat](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/utils-cat.html) to auto-decompress the file and stream it to my mapper? There aren't any code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MRJob can automatically take compressed file formats such as .bz2 and .gz as input and it'll know what to do.